# Is there a good way to do a POJO like structure in bash?

Tags: bash, global-variables

I'm somewhat new to bash scripting.  And I'm looking for an alternative to using global variable in my bash scripts.  I was thinking maybe there might be some kind of structure thing that I'm unaware of that I can group some data points together and pass them to functions.  My current scheme is to set a few global variables and be really careful about where and when they are used.

Is there a better alternative to create data returned from a function in bash than to set global variables?

Comment: Bash 4.3 and newer has namerefs, but I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do. Use associative arrays?

Comment: bash is really quite weak in terms of data structures. There are indexed arrays and associative arrays, and they're really a PITA to pass to functions unless you use namerefs.

Answer (score 0):

An example of using namerefs to pass array *names* to a function:

```
$ dump_array() {
    local -n a=$1
    for i in "${!a[@]}"; do printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${a[$i]}"; done
}

$ declare -a indexed=(a b c d)

$ declare -A associative=([foo]=bar [baz]=qux)

$ dump_array indexed
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d

$ dump_array associative
baz qux
foo bar
```